# How to find out if a method call originated from Test Class

Tags: java, junit

Hii...
Is there any way to find out if the method call originated from a test class? 
If its from a test class... then I need to initialize some dummy values for the variables in the class . I would like to write the Test Class with minimal change in the source code...
The class is following a singleton pattern..So its private constructor gets called which is calling some code which is blocking my testing. So I need to call my dummy methods from within in the private constructor so that it works smoothly..

Currently I am doing this...

```
StackTraceElement[] stack = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
boolean blnFrmTesting = false;
for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stack) {
    if(null != stackTraceElement && null != stackTraceElement.getFileName() && stackTraceElement.getFileName().endsWith("Test.java")) {
        blnFrmTesting = true;
        break;
    }
}
return blnFrmTesting;
```

Is this a correct method...Or is there any other way.. like checking annotation...("@Test")

Answer (score 3):

Well, for the technical part, I suggest you should instead try to see if **class name** contains Test, instaead of file name, which is (although Java specification tries to normalize it) always a little more fuzzy (think about inner class, as an example).

However, in a more general fashion, your code seems to ignore roughly ten years of Java engineering by ignoring the existence of test frameworks (JUniot, TestNG) and their associated ecosystem. Particularly, to define "dummy values", the domain of mocking frameworks is the way to go. There are currently quite a few interesting alternatives :

- [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/)
- [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)
- [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/)
- [JMockIt](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/)

Obviously, they may interfere with your singleton (or not). However, I must tell you that with the davent of IoC frameworks, the singleton pattern is now generally considered to be deprecated.

Comment: Hi...thanks for your help... but I am using mockito in my testing...the thing is when i mock this class.. the static variable initializes in the decalaration itself causing the private constructor to get invoked and subsequently try to call some unwanted methods which i would like to skip...

Comment: I think Riduidel's point is that static initialization make code very hard to test. There are some hacky work-arounds, but that results in either the testcase testing something different than the production code, the production code having functionality that's there only for testing or the test code not providing a complete and readable specification. IoC frameworks and dependency injection can make it possible to guarente that there is only one instance of a class during the life of your application without having static global access or mutable static state, leading to more testable code.

Comment: @NamshubWriter Oh That Neal Stephenson tongue-in-cheek username ! Really like it !

Answer (score 3):

Irrespective of whether you find an answer to this question or not, it might make more sense not to perform this check in the first place, and structure your code accordingly... code which does something else when called by a test isn't really tested, is it?

You could also take a look at using a DI pattern and framework like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/)... that would make things a lot easier to test, while probably resulting in less and simpler code.

Comment: +1 to injection.  If a class needs to "know" about something outside itself, inject it.

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with Sudhir, and do not really understand what did Riduidel want to say recommending to use Mocking. Mocking is fine if you wish to simulate the class' environment and neighborhood.

I think that your method is fine. You can really improve it if you add check of @Test annotation and a fact that the class extends TestCase. If you add support JUniot and testNG you can even publish your code and probably other people can use it.

But I think that probably you can even simplify the method. I used special system property for this purpose. Typically I had to identify that the code is running under application server, so I used property typical for application server. For example jboss.server.name for JBoss and catalina.base for Tomcat. If JUnit does not create any special property you can do it yourself in the beginning of test and check in code.